# Cloth simualtion (pinning) multiple times on the same model

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I'm working up a concept for an interior scene, and not wanting to miss any details, I want to model the window coverings as well. For what I have in mind, I'm pretty sure will need to use cloth sim with pinning, but the pinning application is the problem. With as many places as the object will need to be pinned during the sim, I don't know how to go about setting it up. I've attached a basic reference for an idea of what I'm going for. This will be rendered in cycles when all is said and done also.

[image]

Comment: Are you after a still image or an animation? Do you want to covering to be lifted or stationary during the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a model it should be sufficient to model it by hand using the cloth simulation would be a task too complicated for a model such as this. Using box modeling strategy and maybe subdividing the faces would suffice.

This is Unless you will be animating the model too, then cloth sim is the way to go.

1. Define the basic form of your model.
   [image]
2. You will want to apply Edge Crease at the top and bottom of the model.
3. Apply a subdivision modifier.
   [image]

Comment: I gave that a go, and it looks like I was trying to make things too complicated. It's not going to be animated, I just don't want to miss any of the details, and want to keep it all true to life as much as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, we all tend to make such mistakes starting out.